# Is there a way to identify which google account a tracking code belongs to?

Tags: google-analytics

If I have a Google Analytics tracking code like `UA-234098230948-1`. Is there a way to identify which google account this belongs to? (I guess not, but you'll never know :-))

I wonder because a client of mine has such a account but does not know which google account it is related to (neither email or password).